# i take an array of string and pass it to another second view controller when it pass in second view controller is show empty

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of string and pass it to another second view controller. When it pass in second view controller is show empty.Its show nothing in second view controller.Tell me What can i do that these array are pass and show it into second view controller.

My first View controller:

[image]

My second view controller:

[image]

Comment: Please post code to enable people to help.

Comment: In SecondVC, put the code from `viewDidLoad` in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

In first viewController

```
text.city = cityname
```

In second view controller

```
private var _city:[String] = []

var city:[String] {
    get{
        return _city
    }
    set(city){
        print("city is \(city)")
        Label.text = String(Describing: city)
        _city = city
    }
}
```

Comment: might be because u are sending an array instead of a string in Lable.text

Comment: Check now I used _firstLabel instead of _city

Comment: my code is working but not show in second view controller

Comment: Ur code will work fine but the Label.text will not show any text